# how to copy one storage account data to another using copy activity of ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I am working on a problem statement where I need to copy all containers, along with their data, from one Azure storage account to another using the copy activity of Azure Data Factory (ADF). However, I haven't found any resources stating that we can achieve this using the copy activity of ADF.

I want to know if it is possible to achieve this task or not. If it is, then how can it be done?

I have found that we can achieve it by using AzCopy only. However, if it is possible to accomplish this task using the Copy activity, I would like to know how it can be done.

Comment: This Azure solution isn't enough https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-move-files?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ADLS Gen2 Storage account, you can try the following approach using copy activity.

Take two binary datasets for source storage account and target storage account and don't give any file paths in the dataset.

Give these to copy activity source and sink. In **Source** use the **wild card path** like below.

[image]

In **Sink**, set the Copy behavior to `Preserve hierarchy` copies the files to target in the same hierarchy as source.

[image]

**My source storage account containers:**

[image]

**Containers copied to target Storage account:**

[image]

**NOTE:** In this approach **it ignores the empty containers and empty folders (with no files)** while copying.

If you are using Blob Storage account, then use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2?tabs=azure-ad) to **list out the container names in the source storage account using web activity**.

Give this list to ForEach activity, inside ForEach use the copy activity with source(source storage account dataset) and sink (target storage account).

Give the container name in each iteration `@item()` and it will copy all the containers to target at the end of the ForEach activity.

Comment: thanks @Rakesh, i will defintely try and let you know if haveing any issue